# "Methods to do" vs "Methods for doing"

Tags: word-choice

I have to write a title for an article.

Which will you choose beetwen these two options:

- "Methods to do something"
- "Methods for doing something"

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you used "doing something" instead of giving the title of your article. I'm not sure I'd always give the same answer in every context. The phrase _do something_ could refer to _sort a large data file, graft skin, build a radio, cook a lasagne, detect a submarine, treat Parkinson's disease, make a visitor feel welcome_, or a host of other things. By being vague, you make it harder to give you a precise answer.

Answer (score 4):

At least from the predominant usage point, they do not mean the same thing.

There may be any number of methods 'to do' something but usually just one or a few methods 'for doing' something.

"I want to find a method to solve this equation."
"This is the method for solving this equation."

Note the difference in article use: *a* method *to*; *the* method *for*.

Comment: If @Kris was right, then the difference between them is that *methods to solve X* are just ones of the methods that can solve X, while *the methods for solving X* are all methods that can possibly solve X.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with "methods of doing something". [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) agree, giving more hits for "methods of doing" than for "methods for doing" and "methods to do" combined.

```
                      COCA    BNC

methods of doing       21      21
methods for doing      10       1
methods to do           8       0
```

Comment: I think most would use "Ways to do something" in lieu of "Methods to do something"

Comment: Probably. Hard to tell without knowing the context. *Ways* is more generic and even informal.