# “To solve” vs “For solving”

Tags: grammar

What are the differences between:

“An algorithm to solve optimization problems”

and

“An algorithm for solving optimization problems”

I think only the second one is correct but I can’t explain why the first one is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This question may have been asked before: see [“Methods to do” vs “Methods for doing”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133310/methods-to-do-vs-methods-for-doing). Please search for related questions before asking one, and consider adding your research to the question body.

Comment: @niamulbengali I don't think that particular question counts as an answer to this one. First, there is no way to be sure a priori that *algorithm* and *method* must have the same patterns of complementation by PPs, despite them having roughly similar meanings. (The context is here highly technical, which further muddies the waters.) One must investigate what native speakers actually use in similar contexts. Second, the answer with the most votes in the other question would, if we try to straightforwardly apply it to this question, simply be wrong, as seen in my answer to the present question.

Comment: I think this belongs on ELL, where [Word choice - Way of / to / for](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53441/word-choice-way-of-to-for) probably provides a decent Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable, though searching Google books does suggest that the second version is more common. But the first version definitely isn't wrong; here are some examples from published literature (all titles of papers) written by native speakers:

> *An Algorithm **to Solve** Dynamic Models*
>
> <sup>By Wilbur John Coleman, 1989 [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Algorithm_to_Solve_Dynamic_Models/Ofh8to7Ef04C?hl=en&gbpv=0)</sup>
>
> *An Algorithm **to Solve** the mxn Assignment Problem in Expected Time O (mn log n)*
>
> <sup>By Richard M. Karp, 1978 [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Algorithm_to_Solve_the_M_X_N_Assignme/jWmbGwAACAAJ?hl=en)</sup>
>
> *An Algorithm **to Solve** the Proportional Network Flow Problem*
>
> <sup>By David R. Morrison, Jason J. Sauppe, and Sheldon H. Jacobson, 2014 [(link)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11590-013-0634-5)</sup>
>
> *An Algorithm **to Solve** the Equal-Sum-Product Problem*
>
> <sup>By Michael A. Nyblom and Chelton D. Evans, 2013 [(link)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.3874)</sup>
>
> *An Algorithm **to Solve** the Frobenius Problem*
>
> <sup>By Robert W. Owens , 2003 [(link)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3219081?seq=1)</sup>

For completeness, here are a few titles using the second version:

> *An Algorithm **for Solving** Non-Linear Equations Based on the Secant Method*
>
> <sup>By [J. G. P. Barnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Barnes_(computer_scientist)), 1965 [(link)](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/8/1/66/489886)</sup>
>
> *An Algorithm **for Solving** a Special Class of Tridiagonal Systems of Linear Equations*
>
> <sup>By Donald J. Rose, 1969 [(link)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/362912.362940)</sup>
>
> *An Algorithm **for Solving** the Restricted Least Squares Problem*
>
> <sup>By David Clark, 2009 [(link)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/anziam-journal/article/an-algorithm-for-solving-the-restricted-least-squares-problem/18C1DF8E6F5030CF75AD6E8868B5046B)</sup>
>
> *COG-DICE: An Algorithm **for Solving** Continuous-Observation Dec-POMDPs*
>
> <sup>By Madison Clark-Turner and Christopher Amato, 2017 [(link)](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/2017/638)</sup>